# Receive websocket messages

Tags: python, web-scraping, websocket

Am trying to receive websocket messages from this [Site](https://www.betika.com/en-ke/crash-game/stp_crash_crashx_comet?mode=D) so that I can extract the crash points.

I have tried to write the code below in python

```
import websocket
def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp('wss://sgnlr-stp-gamestream-prod-sanorth-0001.service.signalr.net/client/?hub=crashhub&asrs.op=%2Fbetika-ke%2Fcrash&negotiateVersion=1&asrs_request_id=dL6D5oB7HwA%3D&id=OYotgnvI0OFmEuTnnYiWqAhG0iMwl02&access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IjY5MDQ4NDMxNSJ9.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_aHViPWNyYXNoaHViIn0.xlRyH7DXarnBafpbsr4oiOC1oQprjgwMAmlL0thYyVM', on_message=on_message)
    ws.run_forever()
```

However the code when run does not print the messages containing the crash points.
What can I change in the code to print the messages containing the crash points.